# Issues with CiviDiscount 3.4?

Tags: cividiscount, discounts

After upgrading to CiviDiscount 3.4 and CiviCRM 5.3.1 (on Joomla 3.8.10), autodiscounts for events (based on membership status) work very arbitrarily. E.g. the $20 discount works great, the $35 discount doesn't - config for both is set up exactly the same (except which price options are selected for each, of course). See the screenshot below.

Anyone having autodiscount issues, as well? Can't pin down the root cause so haven't posted on Github yet.

This worked fine on CiviDiscount 3.3 and CiviCRM 5.1.2

Thanks for any ideas

[image]